# check if a varchar exists in another varchar- oracle, not in the same order, with delimeter

Tags: oracle

I want to check if varchar contain another one, 
like this: 
str1 = '1,2,3,4'
str2 = '2,1'

check if  str2 is in str1. in this example, it is, because str1 has both 1 and 2. 
I have to call a simple select from java...
in java I have the string and I need to check if the string from a record in oracle is in the string - but all of this in a simple select!

thank you!

Comment: So really you want to compare all the elements in the lists that are stored in two strings, rather than the strings themselves. Where are these strings coming from? Do you have this kind of data stored in columns, instead of in a proper relational model?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple function to split the delimited strings into collections and then use the `SUBMULTISET` operator to compare them. Like this:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2_TABLE DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       VARCHAR2_TABLE := VARCHAR2_TABLE();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN split_String( '2,1' ) SUBMULTISET OF split_String( '1,3,2,4' )
            THEN 'Matches'
            ELSE 'No match'
            END AS match
FROM  DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
MATCH
-------
Matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each comma-separated list into individual elements, count how many items are in the second list, count how many are in both lists (via a join), and compare the counts:

```
with list1 (item) as (
  select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
),
list2 (item) as (
  select regexp_substr('2,1', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('2,1', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
select count(list1.item), count(list2.item)
from list2
left join list1 on list1.item = list2.item;

                      COUNT(LIST1.ITEM)                       COUNT(LIST2.ITEM)
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                                      2                                       2
```

If the second list had, say, '2,1,5' then the counts would be 2 and 3; since they are different that indicates a mismatch.

If you wanted to just get a flag saying whether they matches you coudl do something like:

```
with ...
select case when count(list1.item) = count(list2.item) then 1 
  else 0 end as matched
from list2
left join list1 on list1.item = list2.item;
```

When the second string is '2,1' that gets 1; when it's '2,1,5' it gets 0.

If the lists might contain duplicates when you could count distinct items. This won't work if either string is empty though.